# Creating a column in R using other column data in a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe in r, df. I wish to take 2 columns of the df (one of which is a 1 period lag of the other), and create a new column based on said values. The rules are supposed to be:

1. Where col_lag[i] == NA, newcol[i] <- col[i]
2. Any row where col[i] == col_lag[i], newcol[i] <- 2
3. Any row where col != col_lag, newcol[i] <- col[i]

It keeps returning a single value instead of a new column

```
col <- c(1,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,1,1)
col_lag <- c(NA,1,1,1,3,3,1,1,3,1)
df <- data.frame(col, col_lag)
func <- function (x,y) {
  for (i in range(1:length(df)){
    if (is.na(y[i])){
      x[i]
    }
    else{
      if (identical(x[i], y[i])) {
        2
      }
      else {
        x[i]
      }
    }
    return(temp)
  }
}

df$newcol <- func(df$col, df$col_lag)
```

In this example i want newcol to be c(1,2,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,2)

Comment: `df$new <- ifelse(df$col==df$col_lag, 2, df$col);
df$new[is.na(df$col_lag)] <- df$col[is.na(df$col_lag)] `

Comment: This is very close apart from that it sets the first value to NA when it should be col[i]

Comment: For correcting this is the second part: `df$new[is.na(df$col_lag)] <- df$col[is.na(df$col_lag)]`

Comment: If you know that only in the first row the value of df$col_lag is NA, then you could simply do: `df$new[1] <- df$col[1]`

Comment: Ok that works now. Thank you!